# "Unable to load popup" every other time

Tags: bug, javascript

In Safari Version 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) and Firefox 12.0 on OS X, I can reproducibly trigger the following error message:

[image: Unable to load popup - please try again (click on this box to dismiss)]

1. Click a link that opens a styled popup (not a dialog box), like *close* or *flag*.
2. Close the dialog by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> or clicking the X button in the upper left.
3. Click a link of the same kind as step 1's again (i.e. any *flag* link on the same page suffices if you selected *flag* before).

Workaround: Click it again, i.e. a third time.

Still, seems to be a bug.

Comment: You're not waiting long enough between step 2 and 3. Simple AJAX deficiency in the SE system that has been around for … like forever. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83278/159624) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99254/159624).

Comment: @slhck Thanks. I noticed this a long time ago but it just bothered me again today. The first link doesn't seem to apply though, given the resolution.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Copied the wrong link. There are one or two other MSO topics IIRC.

Comment: @slhck I hope you enjoy pointing out that I was too lazy to look for related topics ;-) I'll keep this one around in the spirit of "voting for issues" though.

Comment: also works on FF 12/WinXP

Comment: The pop up tells you to try again. I say this is `[status-by-design]` :P